# Displaying featured image or attached image or default in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display an image so that, regardless, at least a default image is displayed on my WP homepage. This is what I came up with:-

```
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                    <?php 
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    } elseif (
                            $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail_id', true); echo 'wp_get_attachment_image($thumbnail_id, '')';
                            )
                         else {
                        <?php echo '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/default-featured.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />'; ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </a>
```

The theory is - if a featured image is assigned to a post, display this first, else, display an attached image (one from the post content), otherwise display my default image. This falls down with error 'unexpected ;'. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
<?php $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail_id', true); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail();
    } else if ($thumbnail_id != "") {
        $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail_id', true);
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($thumbnail_id, '');
    } else {
       echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/default-featured.png" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';
    }
    ?>
</a>
```